# Format Stopwatch Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a jQuery stopwatch that outputs time in the format: `02:45:03`.  However, I need to save the value in the database as minutes. Can anyone tell me how I can convert such a value into minutes? Or, are you aware of any stopwatch that I can use that displays the time in minutes and I would be able to toggle it (pause/resume) and delete instance completely?

Comment: To convert hours into minutes, multiply by 60.

Comment: @KevinBoucher The issue is that it has the ":".  How am I able to strip down the values and do (hours x 60) + minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a fake date to parse the time string into a `Date` object; and then use the `Date` object's methods to extract the hours and minutes and add them together:

```
var time = "02:45:03",
    date = new Date( "1/1/1970 " + time ),
    minutes = date.getHours() * 60 + date.getMinutes();

alert( minutes );
```